# Python: finding sequences in string

Tags: python, string

I have been wondering how can I extract all alpha-numeric non-homogenous sequences from string in python, and if it is possible to do well-styled without using regular expressions.

Under alpha-numeric non-homogenous sequences I mean all sequences like **aA** **a1** **A1** and so on... (no punctuation, only upper/lower cased letters and digits.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid regular expressions? This is by far and away the *most* appropriate time to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re`:

```
import re
re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", "hello there1 A2... bl3h")
#>>> ['hello', 'there1', 'A2', 'bl3h']
```

Not much to it.

If you want anything that's a Unicode digit or character, you could use the upcoming [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module:

```
import regex
regex.findall("[[:alnum:]]+", "hello_there1 A2... bl3h")
#>>> ['hello', 'there1', 'A2', 'bl3h']
```

This should give things iff `thing.isalnum()`.

Comment: You can also use `[[:alnum:]]+`

Comment: Thank you! I found out that regex module was just what I needed for all purposes.

Comment: BTW, `re` does support `\w` for unicodes, no need for `regex`.

Comment: @georg `\w` catches `_` as well, and I didn't want to go the error-prone "`\w` but not these things" route.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum):

```
>>> 'F'.isalnum()
True
>>> '7'.isalnum()
True
>>> ','.isalnum()
False
```

with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) / [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> [c for c in 'ab,cd"12"EF' if c.isalnum()]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '1', '2', 'E', 'F']
>>> ''.join(c for c in 'ab,cd"12"EF' if c.isalnum())
'abcd12EF'
```

or with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) with unbound method:

```
>>> filter(str.isalnum, 'ab,cd"12"EF')
'abcd12EF'
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want characters, but a sequences of characters,  you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(grp) for yes, grp in itertools.groupby('ab,cd"12"EF', key=str.isalnum) if yes]
['ab', 'cd', '12', 'EF']
```

Comment: Note that `"".isalnum() #>>> True`. Also `"໑".isalnum() #>>> True`.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that he wants to extract sequences, not just characters. So the result should be rather `['ab', 'cd', '12', 'EF']`.

Comment: @Veedrac, What's the character. It's not rendered well in my machine. If it is a digit character, that could be what OP want.

Comment: @georg, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @falsetru They are 'DIGIT EIGHT COMMA' (a "8," ligature) and 'LAO DIGIT ONE'. I'm not saying you're wrong, though, as this *might* be wanted.